# Java 2D- Actual Player Collision Detection | Ignore Transparency

Tags: java, 2d, collision, tile

So I'm creating a 2D game platform that works with Tiles. Currently it won't let the player go through the any tiles and works fine. Though rather then stopping the player at a solid tile. I would like to stop the player at an actual object. **Pretend the triangle is in a tile.**

Whats Happening:

[image: What's happening]

What I want:

[image]

I would like the player to be able to walk through the tile until their is no more transparents. Basically walk on the triangle.

```
Player Class http://pastebin.com/SJrzSvVV    
Tile Class http://pastebin.com/V3nqxh61] 
TileMap Class http://pastebin.com/fuj8dR5K
```

Comment: 1. Your description of what you want is not clear. Use more words. Nb your use of "Basically" shows that you yourself don't think it's clear so you added more, but what you added is also unclear.  2. Please edit your code into your question.

Comment: changed the layout of the images, as without it, because of the way the system positions inline images, It was completely unclear to me what text belonged to which picture.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [intersects()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#intersects(double,%20double,%20double,%20double)) method provided by the Java2D API.

You can define the two sprites as shapes and adjust the coordinates when the two shapes intersect. I'm guessing you are splitting up a BufferedImage to create the animation frames.
You can draw a Rectangle or Ellipse frame around your sprites and check those for collisions. The frames do not have to be visible but making them visible helps when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, essentially what I did was I was creating this game using tiles. I created something to scan a tile and find out where it's transparent, and allow players to go through it or not depending on whether the transparency is already inside something in the tile or not.